# Show $f_n(x) = x^{1- \frac{1}{n}} - x$ converges uniformly to 0 as $n \to \infty$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am guessing this can be argued by the monotonicity of the $f_n$, but is there a reasonable way to do it directly? That is, given $\epsilon > 0$ to find $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

I tried using $f_n(x) = x(x^{\frac{-1}{n}}-1) \leq (x^{\frac{-1}{n}}-1)$ but then the convergence is not uniform for $x^{\frac{-1}{n}}-1$ and so this seemed to be no help.

Comment: Hint: Differentiate the function $|f_n|$ in order to find its maximum, then prove that maximum tends to $0$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You can as well use the Dini theorem (an overkill): if $f_n$ is a decreasing sequence of continuous functions convergent pointwise to a continuous function on a closed interval then the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $0 \le x \le \epsilon$ we have $x^{1-\frac  1n} \le \epsilon^{1-\frac  1n}\le \epsilon ^{1/2}$ provided $n \ge 2$. Thus, $f_n(x)\leq \epsilon ^{1/2}+\epsilon$ for $x \le \epsilon$. For $x >\epsilon$ use the fact that $x^{1-\frac  1n} \to x$ uniformly.